# Single JDBC Connection per one user request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have the page for which I should have a several queries from different DAO classes.
I want to use the same connection for all queries. I'm getting the connection from data source for this particular user request.
The idea is to use this connection for all dao methods which are needed for this user request.
I see only one way now - pass connection as param to each DAO method, something like that:

```
productDAO.get(connection, param);
objectDAO.get(connection, param);
```

The question is - is it possible to have another solution for passing connection to different DAO methods for single user request?

The technologies in project: JDBC, Java EE

Comment: use a dbcp - JDBC Connection Pool

Comment: I'm using connection pool but I don't want to open and close connection for each DAO method. I'm going to have one connection per user request for performance goals

Comment: When you close a dbcp connection, it is not closed just returned to the pool

Comment: You're supposed to open and close the connection (although as said, they'll just be returned to the pool). What you're doing now is *wrong*.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot.
It means that I can get the connection from connection pool in each DAO method and it will be no overhead for performance.

Comment: Exactly. Just like you're supposed to.

Comment: Only if you require the DAO calls to run in a single transaction it would maybe make sense to use same connection - but then again this will be handled if you properly open the transaction...